# SQL Stored Procedures for data access

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures, insert

I have been asked to make a simple SQL Person table and to ensure all data access to the SQL table will be via stored procedures.

Can I please have a quick explanation of this statement? Instead of using an Insert statement for the table, do I call a function instead?

If possible, can I have a quick example of using a stored procedure to insert standard information into a database that has the following fields:

- First Name
- Last Name
- Three Address Lines
- Mobile Phone
- Home Phone
- Date Modified
- Person Category

Comment

Comment: We are not here to rephrase and/or copy&paste manuals. Do some research first and ask when you have specific problems.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using MS SQL Server. You could do something like:

```
CREATE TABLE Person
(
    FirstName VARCHAR(25),
    Surname   VARCHAR(25)
)
```

Then your stored procedure (This could be improved by using a transaction, if multiple tables needed be added etc):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_InsertNewPerson
(
    @FirstName VARCHAR(25),
    @Surname VARCHAR(25)
)

AS

BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Person(FirstName, Surname)
    VALUES (@FirstName, @Surname)
END
```

To call the stored procedure:

```
EXEC usp_InsertNewPerson 'Darren', 'Davies'
```

Comment: Thanks. Should I create a new procedure for each individual piece of data for the table? Or do I group them such as PersonDetails, PhoneDetails etc?

Comment: @GarfieldStudent - you only need 1 stored procedure.